# JavaFX - Same actionhandler for MenuItem and a button

Tags: java, button, javafx, menuitem

I'd like to know the answer to the question i asked above. I found a lot about this problem but only with Java Swing and there actionhandling is completely different.
Thanks for the answers and I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What exactlly would you do? You are searching for an Actionhandler for MenuItem or a Button? You only have to google that question -> Here you see something like an Actionhandler! You should specify your question much more / Otherwise its really hard to give you an answer. Your english is not so bad, try to explain your question much more.  Button button2 = new Button("Accept");
        button2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText("Accepted");
            }
        });

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = e -> {
    System.out.println("Action");
};
button.setOnAction(handler);
menuItem.setOnAction(handler);
```